# Posting Boolean to ASP.NET Core 5 Controller Fails for "true" but not true

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I do a post request using curl as follows to an asp.net core 5 controller

```
curl -d "{\"sponsorOnly\":\"true\", \"id\":\"101\"}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:5000/rpc/Email/EmailGenerate
```

It gives me the following error:

```
{
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
  "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "00-7b45947384087a49b8b37125f7424172-a0e14922a4546649-00",
  "errors": {
    "$.sponsorOnly": [
      "The JSON value could not be converted to System.Boolean. Path: $.sponsorOnly | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 21."
    ]
  }
}
```

When I remove the quotes from "true" and make it just true, it works and my controller gets the proper boolean value.  Here is the curl that works:

```
curl -d "{\"sponsorOnly\":true, \"id\":\"101\"}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:5000/rpc/Email/EmailGenerate
```

I have my asp.net core 5 controller as follows:

```
[ApiController]
public class EmailController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost("/rpc/Email/EmailGenerate")]
    public object Post(EmailSendDetail emailSendDetail)
    {
        return new OkResult();
    }...
```

and EmailSendDetail as

```
public class EmailSendDetail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool SponsorOnly { get; set; }
}
```

This use to work (gives me booleans passed into POST method) in ASP.NET but does not in ASP.NET Core.

Comment: @zhulien No it does not. I created a new question here with a lot more details and curl command showing problem.

Comment: A `bool` is a `true`/`false` value, `"true"` is not a `bool`, so the `System.Text.Json` serializer does not admit the value. If you want the old behavior (do you even have a reason for wanting that?) switch to `Newtonsoft.Json`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto my reason I the JavaScript library that is used in the client creates JSON strings for all values regardless of type. Since Newtonsoft.Json is being phased out, I prefer not to use it in my apps. Is there another way to make this work without pulling in Newtonsoft.Json?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Camilo Terevinto already mentioned in the comments, this scenario is not supported. The new default JSON serializer in ASP.NET Core 3.x and later will not parse the strings `"true"` and `"false"` into a boolean. This is also not supported by the [JSON spec](https://www.json.org/json-en.html), which offers boolean literals `true` and `false` instead, and even JavaScript will not parse `"false"` the way you want (`Boolean("false") === true` in JavaScript).

You should change the client so that it will produce proper JSON literals for booleans, so that the default serializer can handle this properly.

Alternatively, you can switch to [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json) which comes with a lot additional built-in behaviors that can parse these strings into booleans. Enabling Newtonsoft.Json for ASP.NET Core 3.x+ applications is described [in the migration guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#newtonsoftjson-jsonnet-support).

Comment: Thanks @poke.  I've been reading about custom converters and trying to figure out if there is a way for that to handle this issue.  I don't have control of the JavaScript client code so unfortunately I'm stuck with what it POSTs. I probably shouldn't resist using newtonsoft, but I've had so many problems over the years with namespace overlaps that having two JSON libraries makes me nervous.

Comment: There is _zero_ overlap in System.Text.Json and Newtonsoft.Json, so you can safely use both at the same time. Also, Newtonsoft.Json is still fully supported and will continue to be supported for longer than whatever current ASP.NET Core version you are currently using.

Comment: Years ago, a Microsoft employee on the asp.net team told me that the reason they were writing their own JSON converters was because Newtonsoft worked great but not in all the scenarios and edge cases that Microsoft needed and that there plan was slowly phase out newtonsoft from their support plan.  Maybe that's changed.